# Access expressions in table

Tags: ms-access, switch-statement, iif

I would collect my IIF or switch expressions in a table as a record(more over 40pcs):

tbl_filter:

Filter

```
Description LIKE '*SCREW*',"Screw"

Description LIKE '*SOCKET*',"SScrew"
```

How could I use this expression-collection in *tbl_filter* in a switch function in a query?

similar like this:

```
SELECT Item, switch(Select * from tbl_Filter) AS Cathegory FROM tbl_Materials
```

thanks for help in advance

Comment: Sorry could you format your post with some more sample data and result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean something like the below.

tbl_Filter

```
Contains    Filter
Screw       Screw
Socket      Sscrew
```

tbl_Main

```
Description
Screws and sockets
Screw
Socket
```

Query SQL

```
SELECT tbl_Main.Description, tbl_Filter.Filter
FROM tbl_Main, tbl_Filter
WHERE tbl_Main.Description Like "*" & [Contains] & "*"
```

Result

```
Description         Filter
Screws and sockets  Screw
Screws and sockets  Sscrew
Screw               Screw
Socket              Sscrew
```

Comment: Hi Fionnuala,
it works fine on one field search. How could i expand it when the criteria belongs to another field too on the same record. 
I mean [Description] conatins a special word(as you solved in the example) and [Item] contains a 'X' charachter then the filter should be 'ScrewHighAlloy'.
That's why i tought to use switch.. but i hang up on getting error..